# migrating NuGet packages from one VSTS account to another

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-server

I am trying to migrate NuGet packages hosted in one VSTS account to a new VSTS account but so far I have not found any CLI tools or scripts to do this. There's some stuff out there like NuGet Mirror but they all seem designed for public feeds only but VSTS needs auth credentials to read/publish packages.

Has anyone migrated packages to a new VSTS account without doing them all one by one?